# my linked list stack won't store data correctly

Tags: c, linked-list, stack

I have this code that gets equations from a .txt file and stores them in a stack, the problem is that when I print them to see the content of the stack, the equations are inverted.

the code is:

```
// C program to Implement a stack
// using singly linked list
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

// Declare linked list node
struct Node
{
    char data;
    struct Node *next;
};

int nodesCount;

// Utility function to add an element `x` to the stack

void push(struct Node **top) // insert at the beginning
{
    FILE *myFile;
    myFile = fopen("equations.txt", "r");
    if (myFile == 0)
    {
        printf("file not opened\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("file opened \n");
    }


    // allocate a new node in a heap
    struct Node *node = NULL;
    node = (struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));

    // check if stack (heap) is full. Then inserting an element would
    // lead to stack overflow
    if (!node)
    {
        printf("Heap Overflow\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    char equation; //to store the current character in the file

    /*
     * initialize the count to 1
     */
    nodesCount = 0;
    while (!feof(myFile))
    {
        /*
         * Use fgetc to read the file by character
         */
        equation = (char)fgetc(myFile);

        // set data in the allocated node
        node->data = equation;
        // set the .next pointer of the new node to point to the current
        // top node of the list
        node->next = *top;
        // update top pointer
        *top = node;

        /*
         * Each time a node is added, it should be allocated new memory
         */
        node = (struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node)); // allocate the memory to new node
        // increase stack's size by 1
        nodesCount += 1;
    }
}

// Utility function to check if the stack is empty or not
int isEmpty(struct Node *top)
{
    return top == NULL;
}

// Utility function to return the top element of the stack
int peek(struct Node *top)
{
    // check for an empty stack
    if (!isEmpty(top))
    {
        return top->data;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("The stack is empty\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

// Utility function to pop a top element from the stack
int pop(struct Node **top) // remove at the beginning
{
    struct Node *node;

    // check for stack underflow
    if (*top == NULL)
    {
        printf("Stack Underflow\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // take note of the top node's data
    int x = peek(*top);
    printf("Removing %d\n", x);
    node = *top;

    // update the top pointer to point to the next node
    *top = (*top)->next;

    // decrease stack's size by 1
    nodesCount -= 1;

    // free allocated memory
    free(node);

    return x;
}



// Utility function to return the nodesCount of the stack
int size()
{
    return nodesCount;
}

int main(void)
{
    struct Node *top = NULL;
    push(&top);

    if (isEmpty(top))
    {
        printf("The stack is empty\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("The stack is not empty\n");
    }

    //Uncomment to check the output :
    struct Node *curr = top;
    while (curr)
    {
        printf("%c", curr->data);
        curr = curr->next;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

the equation.txt file contains:

```
a = ((c+d)*a)/(b/(d-a))
b = 4*[x  +  3*(2*x +  1)]
c =  -5*{3  -  2*[1  -  4*(3  -  22)]}
d = 5  +  2*{[3  + (2*x  -  1)  +  x]  -  2}
e = 5  + 9  * 3
(5 + 9)*3
f  (5  + 9)*3
g = 5  +  2*{[3  + (2*x  -  1)  +  x  -  2}
h = 5 +  9 *  3)
i  = 5  + (9  *  3
```

the output is:

```
�
3  *  9( +  5 =  i
)3  * 9  + 5 = h
}2  -  x  +  )1  -  x*2( +  3[{*2  +  5 = g
3*)9 +  5(  f
3*)9 + 5(
3 *  9 +  5 = e
}2  -  ]x  +  )1  -  x*2( +  3[{*2  +  5 = d
}])22  -  3(*4  -  1[*2  -  3{*5-  = c
])1  + x*2(*3  +  x[*4 = b
))a-d(/b(/)a*)d+c(( = a
```

is there a way to make the output look like the equation.txt file or at least make the parenthesis and other braces look in the correct direction?

Comment: Before casting the return value of `fgetc` to `char`, you should verify that it does not have the value `EOF`. Also, you probably should make the loop condition dependant on the return value of `fgetc`. [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5431941/12149471)

Comment: thats what a stack does, last in first out. Your code works fine

Comment: @pm100: The code works fine, except for the garbage character at the start, which is probably the value `EOF` converted to a `char`, due to incorrectly using `while (!feof(myFile))`.

Comment: one bug, if file not found you code carries on, you need a return. And of course 'push' should really push one item, not a whole file

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed out by someone else in the comments section, a stack is last-in first-out (LIFO). Therefore, it is expected behavior for the data to be inverted.

As far as I can tell, the only bug in your code is the garbage character at the start of the output. The reason for this is is probably that the loop condition

```
while (!feof(myFile))
```

is wrong. You may want to read this for further information:

[Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5431941/12149471)

In that loop, you are using the return value of `fgetc` without first checking whether it is `EOF`. This check should be performed before casting the `int` return value to `char`, because the value `EOF` is not guaranteed to be representable as a `char` (it depends on the compiler), and in cases where it is, it would no longer be distinguishable from an actual character after casting it to `char`.

In the final loop iteration, the function `fgetc` will probably return `EOF`. You are casting this value to a `char` and interpreting it as a character code (although `EOF` is not a character code). This is probably why the last character pushed onto the stack is a garbage character. Consequently, the first character extracted from the stack will be this garbage character (because a stack is LIFO). This explains why the first character in your posted output is a garbage character.

In order to fix this, I recommend that you don't use

```
while (!feof(myFile))
```

as your loop condition, but rather move the `fgetc` function call into the loop condition, like this:

```
while ( ( equation = fgetc(myFile) ) != EOF )
```

However, to ensure that the variable `equation` is able to represent the value `EOF`, you must also change its type from `char` to `int`. Note that the return value of `fgetc` is of type `int`, not `char`, so it should not be converted to `char` until you have verified that it does not have the value `EOF`. Only after that can you be sure that it represents an actual character, and may convert the value to `char`.

Also note that the additional parentheses are necessary, because `!=` has a higher [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) than `=`.